# Increase distance between RowSideColors and the Heatmap using heatmap.2 in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I would like to increase the distance / gap between the RowSideColors and the heatmap generated by heatmap.2 in R. Is there anyway to do this?[Sample image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Alr.png)

Comment: I can't tell you how to do it in heatmap.2. But in [ComplexHeatmap](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/) you can define a Heatmap, a HeatmapAnnotation (equivalent to your RowSideColors) and use `draw` to set the gap between the two

Comment: Thanks! I used complex heatmap and was able to get it to work!